# Find a value within firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application for android and I have reached the point where I have all the products, when I add it to the cart, I add the product ID inside a new child within the current user. If within that new child called "products" I add the IDs of all the products that I give him click when adding to the cart, it remains something like this: **-L_ZXuTy2aVKuzWA1Y6r: "true"**. Where the id of the product I keep as child and I give it a "true" value.

With the following code works perfectly obtaining a complete list of all these products that I have added to the cart and then this list is compared with the child where these products are stored.

Code:

```
followingList = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
    .child( FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
    .child("Products");

reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        followingList.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            followingList.add(snapshot.getKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }});
```

But I want that instead of being stored inside the child "products" directly, a random ID with the push method is created and within each unique ID the product ID that was added to the cart is added.

Currently I can get there, but I do not know how to search inside a random ID all the product IDs that are inside: **child "products" -> random ID -> product ID.** The latter is the one I want to obtain from all the aleatoric IDs that are found.

```
"products" : {
    "-LaSV9Nxwrz58Oe8sLwE" : {
      "-LaQoiF-_v_1BsEiqU7v" : true
    },
    "-LaSXD7-B6E51QRMMoWp" : {
      "-LaQoiF-_v_1BsEiqU7v" : true
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure in words, edit your question to include the relevant data structure in JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add your database schema as also Frank van Puffelen asked for.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ready!